# Network is unreachable in CentOS 7 after disabling Network Manager for cPanel + restart

Tags: centos, networking, cpanel

I have a server from OVH (SoYouStart technically), it's running Proxmox and the VM is running CentOS.

I followed the instructions [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Installation+Guide+-+System+Requirements) and then [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Disable+Network+Manager) to disable the network manager, I installed cPanel and got it working fine. I added extra IP addresses then restarted the server. Now when I try to ping 8.8.8.8 on the server through proxmox's console I get 'Network is unreachable', and I'm unable to connect to the server remotely.

My ifcfg-eth0 file:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
PROXY_METHOD="none"
BROWSER_ONLY="no"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth0"
UUID=...
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
HWADDR=My Virtual Mac from OVH
IPADDR=IP assigned to VPS
PREFIX="32"
GATEWAY=Correct gateway for my OVH server
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

When I run ifconfig -a (Shortening to relevant parts):

```
eth0: ...
inet IPOfVPS netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast: IPOfVPS

eth0cp1-4:
inet IPs netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast: IP but with .255 as the last number
```

I had to retype everything manually since I can't copy/paste from proxmox's console, but the relevant information should be there. If anymore information is needed, let me know in a comment.

To be clear: Networking was working until I restarted, which I only did after finishing the cPanel install and adding additional IPs.

**FIX:** OVH/SYS gives bad advice for using the 'network' service - don't set your gateway to your main IP with .254 as the last number, set it to that VM's IP with .254 as the last number.

Comment: is the network service running? service network start

Comment: 255.255.255.255 netmask is to talk to your own device

Comment: Yup, I tried to run it again just now and it said OK. I run service network status and I get 
Configured Devices: lo eth0 
Currently active devices: lo eth0

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami how do I change my netmask?

Comment: try adding NETMASK=255.255.255.0 to ur ifcfg-th0

Comment: Nope, didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83711/discussion-between-jon-and-yousef-al-hadhrami).

Comment: @roaima the server is from OVH (SoYouStart technically), it's running Proxmox and the VM is running CentOS

Comment: Please would you update your question to make it clear whether it's the Proxmox server that has these configurations or the CentOS VM. You've also mentioned a VPS; what's that? Proxmox?

Comment: Need to see the IP address and Gateway address, please. Change the *first* two octets here if you must, but change them in the same way on both addresses. Also check with OVH what the subnet mask should be and provide that here (in your question) too.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue as here but none of these solutions are helping me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `PREFIX="32"`, which is the same as `NETMASK=255.255.255.255`. Get rid of that, and set a netmask that will allow you to reach your gateway address. You should use either `PREFIX=...` or `NETMASK=...`, but not both.

For reference, `PREFIX="24"` and `NETMASK="255.255.255.0"` are equivalent.

Comment: PREFIX="24" didn't fix the problem. I removed the NETMASK line too

Comment: Is your gateway address contained within the 198.50.192.0/24 network, or does it have some other prefix? Normally, the gateway address for that network would be something like 198.50.192.1. If your intended gateway address is not in that same network, then you're mask/prefix is still not right. Unfortunately, without knowing the details of your network, all I we can do is guess as to what the correct values should be.

Comment: Gateway address is 150.69.254.254

Comment: Changing gateway from 150.69.254.254 to 190.50.192.254 fixed it. The first one is the my main OVH IP but with .254 as the end (Which is what they say to set it to), the second one is the IP of that VM but with .254 as the end. Your prefix comment helped me track down the issue, so I'm rewarding you the bounty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue is routing.

check `ip route` check eth0 is default root properly.

ideally it should be automatically configured by network manger.

exaple of ip route

> ip route
>
> default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  metric 100
>
> 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.106

Comment: ip route: 

169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002 (New line) 198.50.192.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 198.50.192.xxx (Actual IP)